# shortcode with conditional results if logged in

Tags: shortcode

I need some help, I am learning php through wordpress, so I don't really know the php basic and don't really know wordpress either.
so I have this shortcode function:

```
function links( $atts, $content = null ){
    $args = shortcode_atts( array(
        's' => '',
        'l' => '',
    ), $atts);
    
    $api = file_get_contents('API URL'.$args['l']);
    $result1 = '<a href="'. $api .'">'. $args['s'] .'</a>';
    $result2 = '<a href="'. $args['l'] .'">'. $args['s'] .'</a>';

    return THIS IS I NEED THE IF LOGGED IN SHOWS $result2 AND THE OTHERWISE
}
add_shortcode ('link', 'links');
```

the shortcode is already written in custom meta box group text area from foreach.

```
[link s="Google" l="https://google.com"]
```

I write this in  `single.php`

```
echo do_shortcode($linkx['link_box']);
```

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `is_user_logged_in()` in the logic to decide what to return.
See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

I assume `$linkx['link_box']` contains the shortcode.

Comment: when I tried to put ```is_user_logged_in()``` in ```functions.php``` as I input the shortcode there, it doesn't work, I don't know why.

what if I put it on ```single.php``` ?
how does it work?
I mean how I write it?

Comment: nevermind, got it now. my mistake wrong code that it didn't work in the first place. Thank you so much.